# How come set a breakpoing cause MATLAB to crash?

Tags: java, matlab

I wrote a simple web server using MATLAB. Following this the code. The problem is when I comment out while (1) and end. The code has no problem, when I type `http://localhost:85`
the browser received the HTML page correctly. But when I add while loop, I cannot even debug the code, whenever I set a breakpoint, MATLAB crashes, why?

```
    import java.net.* java.io.* java.os.*
    sSocket = ServerSocket(85);
    sSocketClose = onCleanup( @() sSocket.close() );


    while (1)

        cSocket = sSocket.accept();

        iStream = DataInputStream (cSocket.getInputStream() );
        oStream = DataOutputStream(cSocket.getOutputStream());


         Message200Header = ['HTTP/1.1 200 OK', char([13,10]), ...
             'Content-Type: text/html', char([13,10]), ...
             'Connection: close', char([13,10]), char([13,10])];
         oStream.write(uint8(Message200Header), 0 , length(Message200Header));
         page = '<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>';
         oStream.write(uint8(page), 0, length(page));

         iStream.close(); 
         oStream.close();
         cSocket.close();
    end

    sSocket.close();
```

---

I change 
     while (1)
to
     for k = 1:2

when I run the code, MATLAB still crashes.

when I comment out the **while/for** , **end**
and manually run the loop several times, then its OK, why?

Comment: While 1 means the loop will go on infinite and condition is true  and never comes out .so ur server crashes.

Comment: I totally understand what **while** means. But server should run forever. And if you run this piece of simple code ** while true, 1+1, end ** the matlab will never crash